# I have an apache process that takes 98% CPU. How can I find what apache call it runs?

Tags: apache2, process

As you can see below, a single Apache process hangs and takes large amount of CPU resources.
How can I find what http call this apache process runs?

```
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
12554 www-data  20   0  776m 285m 199m R   97  3.7  67:15.84 apache2
14580 www-data  20   0  748m 372m 314m S    4  4.8   0:13.60 apache2
12561 www-data  20   0  784m 416m 322m S    3  5.4   0:58.10 apache2
12592 www-data  20   0  785m 427m 332m S    2  5.6   0:57.06 apache2
```

Comment: install apache satus module you will have a visual of host and url call + status, ex reading request etc. have a look at this here :
https://sourceforge.net/projects/pimpapachestat/

Answer (score 3):

Use [`strace`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strace) with the specific PID. Given your example the syntax would be `sudo strace -p 12554`. You can also use the `-o` option to output to a file since it may be too fast to follow on screen.

The following guides/tutorials may help, since `strace` use and output may not be intuitive for the uninitiated:

> - [How to use strace - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174942/how-to-use-strace)
> - [7 Strace Examples to Debug the Execution of a Program in Linux](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/11/strace-examples/)
> - [Linux Server Troubleshooting With strace](http://www.linuxplanet.com/linuxplanet/tutorials/7229/1)
> - Google for many more resources...

Comment: I used strace and this is what I see in endless loop:

poll([{fd=41, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI}], 1, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {191119, 521541040}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {191119, 521579361}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {191119, 521619004}) = 0
gettimeofday({1349194313, 932472}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({1349194313, 932517}, NULL) = 0
poll([{fd=41, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI}], 1, 0) = 0 (Timeout)

Any idea what I can learn from this?